# Displaying File Icon in Linked Data Source

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a linked source which includes lots of doc libs in a sharepoint site. I want to show these files' icon. I used code block below :

```
<xsl:if test="@ContentType = 'Document'">
<img src=”/_layouts/images/ic{@File_x0020_Type}.gif”>
</xsl:if>
```

But it could not find the image. Do  i need to activate some features?

Thanks in advence

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to use code, then you get the icon url of your document like this:

```
            SPListItemCollection itemcoll = web.Lists["ListName"].GetItems();            
        foreach (SPListItem item in itemcoll)
            {                    
                   string docIcon = SPUtility.ConcatUrls("/_layouts/images/", SPUtility.MapToIcon(item.Web, SPUtility.ConcatUrls(item.Web.Url, item.Url), "", IconSize.Size16));
                
            }
```

Comment: unfourtanetely i am not, also i  think that images dont exists in the related path. So i thought may be there is a feature that i should activate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<img alt="Type" src="/_layouts/images/{ddwrt:MapToIcon('', ddwrt:GetFileExtension(string(@FileLeafRef)))}"/>
```